# Amazon Web Services (AWS) - Amazon Linux: How to install libel-dev and g++?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminal, yum

I just started an AWS EC2 instance using an Amazon linux instance. I tried installing libel-dev and g++ like `sudo yum libel-dev g++ make`, but I get:

```
No package libssl-dev available.
No package g++ available.
```

So how can I install libel-dev and g++?

Thank you and will be sure to vote up/accept answer!

Comment: update your yum repository by running command  `yum update -y` and then run `yum list` and see if these packages are available ? if not then you need to add a repo to your yum repo where these packages are available.

Comment: let me know if it solves your issue?

Comment: Can you share which flavor of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 6):

For libssl equivalent, this one worked `sudo yum install openssl-devel -y`

For g++,  `sudo yum install gcc -y`

Comment: does this install libssl3.so?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged yum, I'm assuming it the package manager you're using on your OS.

Whenever you install a fresh OS, it's always a good idea to update your package manager, be it apt-get or yum.

Do an update on the same (`yum update -y`) and if does not, you might have to compile the same from source.
You can learn more about compiling from source here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173/how-to-compile-and-install-programs-from-source

Answer (score 0):

@Efren's command `sudo yum install gcc -y` didn't install `g++` for me, and why should it?

I was able to get `g++` by switching my OS from `Amazon Linux 2` to `Deep Learning AMI GPU PyTorch 1.12.0 (Amazon Linux 2)`. It comes pre-installed.

Comment: See documentation on AL2 packages, OP is on AL not explicit to 1 or 2 but in any case packages are managed by AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#package-repository